# Change picture based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I am trying to implement a script which changes images "every time" user scrolls down.

I read something about and I think the best practice is replace images once user reach a specific scroll position.

The website will have 3 main sections:
1) introduction: the core message + "instruction" to use;
2) animation: when user scrolls down, the animation will show. So every 10 pixel (or more/less) the image changes but the user keeps seeing the same section. It is a sort of GIF in which user has the control of the timing. It is useful in order to let the user able to see every drawing (or to go faster if they don't want to see all).
3) conclusion: last message + my contact.

Each section will have "100% of the device height" and "100% of the device lenght" (each device will have its own dimension). These numbers are just useful to let you understand.

In other words, the "animation" will follow this path:
1) first image at 0 pixel (from top, for example);
2) second image at 10 pixel (from top, for example) which replaces the first one;
3) third image at 20 pixel (from top, for example) which replaces the second one;
4) fourth image at 30 pixel (from top, for example) which replaces the third one;
ecc.

Do you know a way to implent this script?

Answer (score 0):

I would fire an event every time the page is scrolled then get the position of the top of the target element, and then do my logic there. Here is a code sample:

```
// can be any target
$(body).scroll( function () {
  // your even fired on scroll - get the offset of the closet parent element
  // you will likely loop here
  var position = $("elementYouWantToGetOffSetFor").position(); 
  if(position.Top >= previousElementsTop) // guessing you need to check it against closest sibling
{ 
  // then do your image swap here 
  $("yourtargetimage").src("pathtowherethisis");
}
});
```